# Steps to save data to a DB in sql server from android app?

Tags: android, sql-server, database

I have connected my database from sql server to my android app and get an output and everything runs fine.I just need help with a register page where I want to save data that has been entered into edittext boxes tothe database but cant seen to get the correct method for this. Any help or guide lines would be very much appreciated thanx :-D

Comment: I know you can trough Android -> php -> database. It is possible to give a variable from your app to the php file, there you can make a query. Using variable like username and password. ->Don't got an example at this moment, working on old laptop (new one is broken). Don't got my examples yet on this one.<-

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at DBHelper class, Hope it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Oh, forgot I had some files on my mail :).
Here is a little example:
Java (android):

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username","%"));

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("location php file");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Php:

```
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (UserName) VALUES '".$_REQUEST['Username']."'");
```

I thought it was something like this. You may need to change it a little, but you have a start here.